# Unable to add media stream to video element

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc, simplewebrtc, openwebrtc

I am trying to pass a media stream from page 1 to page 2. I am getting a media stream with the same ID on page 2 as the media stream generated on page 1. But I am not able to add this media stream to the video tag that is present in the page 2 HTML code.

I have tried creating srcObject to the video element and also tried adding the media stream as URL.

```
const remoteVideo = document.querySelector('#remoteVideo');
function gotRemoteStream(event) {
  console.log('got remote stream');
  try {
    remoteVideo.srcObject = event.streams[0];
    console.log('added remote stream');
  } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
  }

  console.log(remoteVideo.srcObject);
}
```

The last console.log returns -

```
MediaStream {id: "P7pInpAX7ee32KJOsPRNxZWEcdjjAg5Sq7pk", active: true, onaddtrack: null, onremovetrack: null, onactive: null, …}
```

But this media stream does not get added to the video element tag in

```
<video id="remoteVideo" src="" playsinline autoplay></video>
```

Comment: how do you route from page1 to page2 ? Are you using some kind of framework like angular, react js or Vue?

Comment: I am using node(express) and socket.io.

Comment: As far as I see your second page is not aware of your media stream. How are you passing it from page 1 to page 2 ?

Comment: I am trying to implement WebRTC. So I am using TURN servers for signalling and the media transfer is supposed to be peer to peer.